# batch file command

Tags: sql, command-line, batch-file

i want to write a query to a file...
echo select * from emp where salary >= 0 >>emp.sql

but it refuses to accept >= symbol as > used for redirection...

any other way?

I want to write the query in the program itself....
not by passing already written file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `^` character

```
echo 1 ^< 2
```